# AdaCore gnatstudio builds but won't run

Tags: macos, gnat

Mac mini (2018)
OSX 10.15.5
XCode 11.5
GNAT 2020
Miniconda environment python 3.7.7

I have built gnatstudio from https://github.com/AdaCore/gps-master.
However, the command gnatstudio/obj/gnatstudio fails with:
dyld: Library not loaded: /gnatmail/sandbox/a2c2/x86_64-darwin/gcc-c/pkg/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Volumes/Data/Applications_Packages/gps-master/gnatstudio/obj/gnatstudio
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      gnatstudio/obj/gnatstudio

I can find no reference to /gnatmail/sandbox/a2c2/x86_64-darwin/gcc-c/pkg/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib in my gps build instructions; not in any Makefile or gpr.
I have found libstdc++.6.dylib in /opt/GNAT/2020/lib, /opt/GNAT/2019/lib/gps and a few other less relevant locations.

Comment: Building with libstdc++ was deprecated with Xcode 8 and is does not seem to be  supported in Xcode 11.

Comment: The solution seems to be to replace references to libstdc++ with libc++.   Therefore, I have changed -lstdc++  to -lc++.   The Library not loaded message no longer occurs so these changes seem to have fixed that problem.